brightness is very low on hp victus 15
i have double booted my system with ubuntu 24.04 lts before this i booted with 22.04 lts but in that also after installing the ubuntu the brightness was very low, i tried all the things to set that issue but unable to fix it, then i thought it must be due to the older version then i deleted that version and reinstalled ubuntu 24.04 lts but in this version i am facing the same issue that the brightness is very low, although when i boot to the windows11 os the brightness and every things work properly but at the same time when i boot to ubuntu the issue of low brightness occurs. I dont know how to fix it please help me out this

Try looking at this it may give you some clues. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1518261/hp-elitebook-8760w-ubuntu-24-04-nvidia-4000m-dreamcolor-screen-brightnes

I just had this on HP 8760w with 24.04 the fix for me was this.
The Keyboard " Hot keys " for brightness and the Display " Slider " (click on the Top right corner of Display) both adjust and the " Hot keys " even bring up an on screen widget to show Display Brightness is being adjusted.
BUT, the Display does not change, it stays DULL!?


In terminal, type
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

or browse to /etc/default and open the grub file located there.

Then search for the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX and add
acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=native 

inside the " ".
Search in the GRUB file for these two entries and change the second line to this:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux  acpi_backlight=native"

(If this does not work try "vendor" or "video" in place of native)

Now run in terminal:
sudo update-grub


Restart the PC and Slider and Fn+F9/F10 should now work correctly and Brightness will change :)


